# YUP validation for iteration(looping) the JSON in react native

Tags: react-native, validation, yup

I am using YUP validation, By using validation for TextInput. It doesn't have value, Will shows error message("Required") then after feeding the value it will be hidden, But the iteration(looping) can perform, Even clicking the value the "Required" error message showing. But handle submit will work, I need to solve this issue.

Initially "Required" error message will show ,If I click the value "Required" message will be hidden, This need to implement in my project

```
const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    staffName:selectTutor.length === 0 ? Yup.string().required('Required'): null,
    batchName: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    type: type.length === 0 ? Yup.string().required('Service type is required') : null,
    fees: Yup.number().typeError("Must be a number").required('Required'),
    startTime: startTimeselect.length === 0 ? Yup.string().required('Start time required') : null,
    endTime: endTimeselect.length === 0 ? Yup.string().required('End time required') : null,
    days: days.length === 0 ? Yup.string().required('Day is required') : null,
    studentsAllowed: Yup.number().typeError("Members allowed must be a number").required('Required').min(1, "No of Members allowed must be 1 or more"),

});




<Formik initialValues={{ batchName: '', description: '', fees: '', sportsType: '', startTime: '', endTime: '', days: '', studentsAllowed: '', locationId: '' }}
    validationSchema={LoginSchema}
    onSubmit={async (values) => {

}}

>
{({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors,
    isValid }) => (

    <View style={{ width: '100%', paddingHorizontal: 25, marginVertical: 20 }}>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Batch Name</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                onBlur={handleBlur('batchName')}
                value={values.batchName}
                onChangeText={handleChange('batchName')}
            />
            {errors.batchName &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.batchName}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>

            <Text style={styles.label}>Description</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.des}
                multiline={true}
                numberOfLines={5}
                onBlur={handleBlur('description')}
                value={values.description}
                onChangeText={handleChange('description')}
            />
            {errors.description &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.description}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Fees</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                onBlur={handleBlur('fees')}
                value={(values.fees).trim()}
                onChangeText={handleChange('fees')}
            />
            {errors.fees &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.fees}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Service Type</Text>

            <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal>

                {subCategory !== null && subCategory !== undefined && subCategory.map((item, index) => (
                    <View key={'subb' + index}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleChangeColor(item.typeCategoryId)}>
                            <View style={[type && type === item.typeCategoryId ? styles.weekSelected : styles.weekUnselected, styles.shadow, { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 7, marginVertical: 2 }]}>
                                <FastImage
                                    source={{ uri: 'https://acadapps.s3.amazonaws.com/' + item.thumbnailPath, priority: FastImage.priority.normal }}
                                    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
                                    style={styles.recommendedImage}
                                />
                                <Text style={{ color: type && type === item.typeCategoryId ? '#fff' : '#757575', fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_TITLE, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.categoryName}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </View>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
            {errors.type &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.type}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Time</Text>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_SUBTITLE, fontSize: 16, color: 'black', marginLeft: 3, marginTop: 3 }}>Starts at</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.time}
                    onBlur={handleBlur('startTime')}
                    value={startTimeselect}
                    editable={false}
                />

                {showStartTime && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        testID="dateTimePicker"
                        value={datePickerStartTime}
                        mode={"time"}
                        onChange={onChangeStartTime}
                    />
                )}
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onFocusStartTime()} >
                    <Ionics name={'clock'} size={35} color={materialTheme.COLORS.BUTTON_COLOR} style={{ paddingTop: 2, paddingLeft: 10 }} />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

            </View>

            {errors.startTime &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.startTime}</Text>
            }
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_SUBTITLE, fontSize: 16, color: 'black', marginLeft: 3, marginTop: 2 }}>Ends at</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={[styles.time, { marginLeft: 18 }]}
                    onBlur={handleBlur('endTime')}
                    value={endTimeselect}
                    editable={false}
                />

                {showEndTime && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        testID="dateTimePicker"
                        value={datePickerEndTime}
                        mode={"time"}
                        onChange={onChangeEndTime}
                    />
                )}
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onFocusEndTime()} >
                    <Ionics name={'clock'} size={35} color={materialTheme.COLORS.BUTTON_COLOR} style={{ paddingTop: 3, paddingLeft: 10 }} />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
            {errors.endTime &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.endTime}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Days</Text>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_TITLE, marginTop: 6 }}>Select/Unselect All</Text>
                    <CheckBox
                        value={selectAll}
                        onValueChange={value => {
                            setSelectAll(value);
                            if (value) {
                                setDays(['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']);
                            } else {
                                setDays([]);
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    />
                </View>
            </View>

            {/* <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal> */}
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%' }}>
                {
                    weekdays.map((item, index) => (
                        <View key={'abc' + index} >
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleChangeDays(item.value)}>
                                <View style={[days && days.includes(item.value) ? styles.daySelected : styles.dayUnselected, styles.shadow]}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: days && days.includes(item.value) ? '#fff' : '#757575', fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_HEADER, fontSize: 13, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                    ))
                }
            </View>
            {/* </ScrollView> */}
            {errors.days &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.days}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>No of Members allowed</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                onBlur={handleBlur('studentsAllowed')}
                value={(values.studentsAllowed).trim()}
                onChangeText={handleChange('studentsAllowed')}
            />
            {errors.studentsAllowed &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.studentsAllowed}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Staff Name</Text>               
            {tutorList.length === 0 ?
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CreateStaff")}>
                    <View style={[styles.shadow, { width: '44%', height: 60, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#FFF', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 7, marginVertical: 2, flexDirection:'row' }]}>
                        <Text style={{fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_TITLE, fontWeight: 'bold', marginRight:5 }}>{'Add Tutor Staff'}</Text>
                        <Ionic name={'plus'} size={20} color={materialTheme.COLORS.BUTTON_COLOR} /> 
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                :
            <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal>
                {tutorList !== null && tutorList !== undefined && tutorList.map((item, index) => (
                    <View key={'styp' + index}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleChangeStaff(item.staffId)}>
                            <View style={[selectTutor && selectTutor === item.staffId ? styles.weekSelected : styles.weekUnselected, styles.shadow, { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 7, marginVertical: 2 }]}>
                                <Text style={{ color: selectTutor && selectTutor === item.staffId ? '#fff' : '#757575', fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_TITLE, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.staffName !== null && item.staffName.length > 8 ? `${item.staffName.substring(0, 8)}...` : item.staffName}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </View>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
             }
            {errors.staffName &&
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_BODY, fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.staffName}</Text>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', marginTop: 20 }}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handleSubmit}>
                <View style={[styles.btn, { width: buttonClick ? '20%' : '75%' }]}>
                    {!buttonClick &&
                        <View>
                            <Text style={[styles.btntext, { fontFamily: materialTheme.FONT.LABEL_HEADER }]}>Create</Text>
                        </View>
                    }
                    <View>
                        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color={'#fff'} animating={buttonClick} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>

    </View>
)}
</Formik>
```